# Memory padding and alignment for local functions in C/C++

Tags: memory, struct, padding, memory-alignment

I know what padding and alignment is and how is it used in structs in C/C++.
My question is do I need to minimize the padding in variables inside local functions also or they have almost negligible memory.

Comment: local variables are allowed to be re-ordered in memory by the compiler anyway (unlike struct members), so you are best off leaving that task up to the compiler.

Comment: "variables inside local functions" or rather **local variables**?

Comment: Local variables only.